# Problems with trying to open Contacts list?

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I've seen a ton of posts online that show "how to open the Android contacts list" but they're all outdated and some of the code doesn't even work anymore.

EDIT:

Now have the following:

```
public class MessagePreview extends Activity {
final int PICK_CONTACT = 3;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button recipientContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddRecipient);

    recipientContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (reqCode) {
    case (PICK_CONTACT):
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                String name = c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NAME));
                // TODO Whatever you want to do with the selected contact
                // name.
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
 }
```

No errors, but it does say

- The field Contacts.PeopleColumns.NAME is 
   deprecated

  - The type Contacts.People is deprecated
  - The field Contacts.PeopleColumns.NAME is 
    deprecated
  - The type Contacts.People is deprecated

on this line:

String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NAME));

I have to add more code after that line, but I don't know what to add.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to define a method inside of another method. That does not work. Please move your definition of `onActivityResult()` to be a method on your `Activity`.

FWIW, [here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Contacts/Pick) that picks a contact that works on Android 1.5-4.0.3.

Comment: So move it outside of the onClickListener for recipientContact?

Comment: @Cole: Yes. `onActivityResult()` **must** be implemented on your `Activity`.

Comment: @Cole: Your error is self-explanatory: you are passing a string (the output of `getColumnName()`) to a method that takes an `int` (`getString()`). Also, `Contacts.KIND_PHONE` is not the name of a column. Besides, your query did not request *any* columns to return.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] projection    = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER };
Cursor names = getContentResolver().query(contactData , projection, null, null, null);
int indexName = names.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
int indexNumber = names.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
names.moveToFirst();
do {
  String name   = names.getString(indexName);
  String number = names.getString(indexNumber);
} while (names.moveToNext());
```

try this code on onactivityforresults